# Laravel 5.3: Can not access anymore the admin dashboard

Tags: php, database, laravel, model

anyone can help me here with a problem?

I'm creating one area in Laravel where Users can login accordingly to their role.

Used an artisan command to create the auth, quite straightforward so far.

Then, I started by changing the table name and the primary key of the table 'users' in the DB.
With this done, one needs to update the User Model (automatically generated by the artisan command) and let the model know where exactly is the table 'users' and which one is the primary key for that table.

```
protected $table = 'users';
protected $primaryKey = 'userID';
```

After this, once I go to the browser and do a normal login, it doesn't let me access the admin dashboard and I'm getting prompt with ***trying to get a property of a non-object.***

This comes from the fact that once the table and the primary key are changed like I've done before, '**$this**' is not in object context anymore.

How can I make it work?

User.php:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{


(...) public function isAdmin(){


        if($this->roles->Role_Type  == "Admin" && $this->is_active == 1){        //this one is the line 83 where the error is


            return true;

        }


        return false;



    }




 (...)

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan dump-autoload` ?

Comment: I've tried now and the problem still continues.
Actually used: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: you should use artisan comman instead. It clears Laravels compiled sources. 
What is the full exception message?

Comment: it tells me the command is not defined (Command "dump-autoload" is not defined).
Sorry for the late reply

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you used L5.3. Yes, the command is removed in L5. But still: what is the full exception message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked this way:

went to the DB and deleted the strong relationships (FKs) stablished between the tables, they're always a pain for Developers, requiring much more code just to have them there.

Thanks to you all for all the help and bellow is the code that used and worked fine:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    //
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'userID';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'roleID',
        'photoID',
        'is_active'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];



    public function role(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'roleID');


    }



    public function photo(){


        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo', 'photoID');


    }




//    public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
//
//
//        if(!empty($password)){
//
//
//            $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
//
//
//        }
//
//
//        $this->attributes['password'] = $password;
//
//
//
//
//    }



    public function isAdmin(){


        if($this->role->Role_Type  == "Admin" && $this->is_active == 1){


            return true;

        }


        return false;



    }



    public function posts(){


        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');


    }



    public function getGravatarAttribute(){


        $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($this->attributes['email']))) . "?d=mm&s=";
        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$hash";


    }





}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have error in this code

```
$this->roles->Role_Type
```

"$this->roles" returns the roles corresponding to that user and then you taken the field "Role_Type".

In your scenerio, there is no roles attached to that user.

So this "$this->roles" returns null.

So you could not take the value "Role_Type". This causes error.

You have to do the following

```
if($this->roles != null && $this->roles->Role_Type && $this->is_active == 1) {        
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Note: your code will work with has one relationship.

```
Class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
    }
}
```

If you want to use roles and permission in effecient manner, try this package https://github.com/romanbican/roles